# Generate connect keys for HMAC programmatically

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

When I add a custom connect configuration, also I want to include the HMAC signature.

connectCustomConfiguration.IncludeHMAC = "true"

Is there a way to create and get a connect key when a connect adding ?

[image: connect key]

Answer (score 2):

The functionality to generate an HMAC key programmatically is in active development now. Details should be available in the next few months. Keep an eye on release notes until then!